# Double quotes in String.Concat

Tags: c#

I want to write

> Label "BuildingData" does not exist.

I know how to write using String.format and stringbuilder. I want to write this using String.Concat.

When I write code

```
String.Concat("Label ","\"","BuildingData","\"", "does not exist.")
```

The output is

> Label \"BuildingData\" does not exist.

Comment: I think you're looking at the debugger. http://ideone.com/ImfHDg

Comment: You're viewing it in a debugger, which is escaping the quotes for you. Your code is correct. (Except you're missing a space between the second quote and "does")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a space before `does` and you'll get the correct output. The quotes are a red herring - you're looking in the debugger.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var concat = String.Concat("Label ","\"","BuildingData","\"", " does not exist.");

        Console.WriteLine(concat);
    }
}
```

[Here's the output](http://ideone.com/ImfHDg).